# Blender Shrink/Fatten Issue

Tags: mesh

I have a mesh that I want to shrink but when I try to...it doesn't really go well (see GIF).
Someone has a fix for this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X59m.jpg

Comment: Hi. While videos can be good, ideally all question content should be in the question body, in the form of good descriptions of the issue and images. Also, please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the current version of Blender(2.83.4 at the time of writing) you would not have such an issue. In 2.79 this operation used to not work correctly with Individual Origins selected as pivot point for transform operations. Select another to fix this:

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thanks!